# My latex broke, possibly corrupted amsmath package

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I have come across a very unusual (for me at least) situation.

For whatever reason, after using tex for quite some time, today my latex just gave error message:

"File ended while scanning use of @newenv."

The problem is that it gives the same message to almost every tex file I have, without modifying them, and without previous similar error.
Eventually, I found out that the problem occurs in tex files that uses the "amsmath" package.

The problem is definitely not something about missing "}"s in the documentation.
Did my amsmath package got corrupted somehow, or could there be something I am missing?

Comment: Did you do an update of any packages or the kernel recently?

Comment: No, but right now, I have uninstalled latex, and installed a newer version. Unfortunately, the error seems to still be there.

Comment: Which TeX distribution, and which front-end editor, do you employ

Comment: `\@newenv` is an internal part of `\newenvironment`  you would get the stated error from `\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{zz}{}{

\begin{document}

\end{document}
`   It is possible to get that if you have truncated `amsmath.sty` mid-definition. add to your question a small but complete test file and show the _full log_ that you get

Answer (score 1):

The error relates to an incomplete `\newenvironment` declaration so the most natural way to get it is a document such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{zz}{}{

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

which produces a terminal output of

```
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)))
Runaway argument?
{ \par \begin {document} \par \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

However the `amsmath` source file `amsmath.sty`  does use `\newenvironment` so if you have somehow truncated it the same error is possible.

If I truncate the file then the document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

poduces the terminal output

```
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
Runaway argument?
{ 
! File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

The things to note are the different form of the log specifically

```
(./amsmath.sty
```

gives the full path  to `amsmath.sty`  and shows a local copy here. and that in this case there is no `)` that matches this `(`  (just two `)` not three `)` on the line before the error message, This indicates that the error is triggered in code in the file `amsmath.sty` which is still open, not as in the first case an error in the document.

So the full log will allow you to find the file that has the broken `\newenviornment`.

Comment: It's still better to reinstall all files, because some other files may be truncated too.

Comment: @user202729 perhaps but most likely not, in coments the op said that did not help which suggests as I show here a local file that just needs deleting. impossible to say for sure until a log is shown